# How can I build/deploy an angular 2 project to production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have created a site using Angular 2. I started making my site using the [Angular 2 QuickStart Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) as base and it's working like it should if I use the command `npm start`. Now that the site is finished I need to build/deploy (don't know the correct definition) to production so the site can be access to the client. The question is: how to I build this project for production? (without the need to run `npm install`)

The best thing I could found was to to try `ng build -prod`, but it says that my project is not a cli project. How to a generate the independent files to open just the `index.html`page and access the site? Is it possible?

**Update:**

Maybe I was not clear: what I'm looking for is a way to get all the TypeScripts files and build it in a pure HTML/JavaScript/CSS site ready to display. No compression or minify needed at the moment. Is it possible? If not, what are other solutions (preferably independent on the host)?

Comment: Deploying depends on your stack, servers, ops team, and a million other factors. Anything we can tell you would be pure opinion, which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm searching how to generate the independent files so I can open the index and open the site like a pure html/js/css site. I thought it was possible, but it seems that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really bad at dealing with webpack and wasn't able to Anthony Ikeda solution or any other solution I found on web. If anyone get stuck in this like me, my solution was to use [Angular Cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). I create a new project with angular cli, create all the pages, components and services with angular cli and copied the code from the old no-cli project to this new cli project. With a cli project, I used the `ng build` command to build the project and get the files to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand from using Angular2 the last few weeks is what you're essentially creating is a client-side single page app so all you need to deliver is the HTML page with references to the respective JavaScript files.

I've been investigating WebPack for packaging an application (and still in the middle of getting it right), however, WebPack will combine all the compiled typescript files into a single (or multiple, still working on this part) Javascript files while also injecting the reference to the javascript files into your index.html page.

My current project compiles the typescript files (using gulp) using a web pack config to configure the output javascript file (main.ts -> main.js):

```
gulp.task("build-tsc", function() {
    return gulp.src("entry.js")
        .pipe(webpack( require("../../../webpack.config.js")))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
});
```

My web pack.config.js looks like (the webpack module ignores the fact I don't have an entry.js):

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "main": "./src/app/main.ts",
    "share": "./src/app/share_main.ts",
    "polyfills": "./src/app/polyfills.ts"
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['main', 'share', 'polyfills']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

My original codebase is:

```
src/
    index.html
    assets/
        styles/
            main.scss
    app/
        app.component.ts
        app.routes.ts
        app.module.ts
        share_main.ts
        polyfills.ts
        dashboard/
            dashboard.component.ts
            dashboard.html
        navbar/
            navbar.component.ts
            navbar.html
```

So what I end up with (post build) is a new dist/ directory with the files in place for use:

```
dist/
    index.html
    main.js
    share.js
    polyfill.js
    app/
        dashboard/
            dashboard.html
        navbar/
            navbar.html
    styles/
        main.css
```

Right now I'm using browserSync for now to serve the files for dev purposes, but you theoretically should be able to serve them up as static content via NGINX, Apache or proxy them through NGINX/Apache to lite-server.

The idea behind WebPack is that you give it an entry point (in this case main.ts) and it crawls the import statements ensuring that anything it encounters is added to the resulting Javascript files then adds them to the index.html file automatically.

Like I mentioned I've got a working app but I'm trying to understand the "multiple entry points" better but the above should work just the same.

Comment: Just realise, the build-tsc gulp task is just one task coordinating the efforts of creating the dist/ directory.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at your answer. What I'm trying to do is to create static files that can be open like a normal site without angular.

Comment: How do you mean "without angular"?

Comment: I mean without npm. When making a site you have a bunch of html/js/css files and you just open the html file on browser to see the site. I would like to have the TypeScript files converted to JavaScript and HTML static files ready to run. I can only run the application with the `npm start` command at the moment.

Comment: That's the above solution I just gave you. No need for running npm, just set up the files on NGINX or CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this solution and it works perfectly for me (only html + css + js files) ... only minification give me some problems.

My webpack.config.js:

```
/// <binding />
var environment = (process.env.NODE_ENV || "development").trim();

if (environment === "development") {
    module.exports = require('./webpack.dev.js');
} else {
    module.exports = require('./webpack.prod.js');
}
```

My webpack.dev.js

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "polyfills": "./polyfills.ts",
        "vendor": "./vendor.ts",
        "app": "./app/main.ts",

    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },
    output: {
        path: "./app_build",
        filename: "js/[name]-[hash:8].bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: "babel-loader",

                // Skip any files outside of your project's `src` directory
                //include: [
                //  "app_build",
                //],
                exclude: [
                  path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
                ],
                // Only run `.js` and `.jsx` files through Babel
                test: /\.js/,

                // Options to configure babel with
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator'],
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "ts"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "html"
            },
            //{
            //    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
            //    loader: "file?name=assets/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]",
            //},
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
                //include:  path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/img"),
                loader: 'file?name=/assets/img/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
              //  exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file?name=/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            // Load css files which are required in vendor.ts
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name]-[hash:8].bundle.css", { allChunks: true }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ["app", "vendor", "polyfills"]
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(
            [
                "./app_build/js/",
                "./app_build/css/",
                "./app_build/assets/",
                "./app_build/index.html"
            ]
        ),
        // inject in index.html
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html",
            inject: "body"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        //contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "app_build/"),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: "minimal"
    }
};
```

My webpack.prod.js:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
var BabiliPlugin = require("babili-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "polyfills": "./polyfills.ts",
        "vendor": "./vendor.ts",
        "app": "./app/main.ts"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },
    output: {
        path: "./app_build",
        filename: "js/[name]-[hash:8].bundle.min.js"
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
           {
               loader: "babel-loader",

               // Skip any files outside of your project's `src` directory
               //include: [
               //  "app_build",
               //],
               exclude: [
                 path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
               ],
               // Only run `.js` and `.jsx` files through Babel
               test: /\.js/,

               // Options to configure babel with
               query: {
                   plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator'],
                   presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
               }
           },
           {
               test: /\.ts$/,
               loader: "ts"
           },
           {
               test: /\.html$/,
               loader: "html"
           },
           //{
           //    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
           //    loader: "file?name=assets/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]",
           //},
           {
               test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
               //include:  path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/img"),
               loader: 'file?name=assets/img/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
           },
           {
               test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
               //  exclude: /node_modules/,
               loader: 'file?name=/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
           },
           // Load css files which are required in vendor.ts
           {
               test: /\.css$/,
               loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
           },
           {
               test: /\.scss$/,
               loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
           },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name]-[hash:8].bundle.css", { allChunks: true }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ["app", "vendor", "polyfills"]
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(
            [
                "./app_build/js/",
                "./app_build/css/",
                "./app_build/assets/",
                "./app_build/index.html"
            ]
        ),
        // inject in index.html
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html",
            inject: "body"
        }),
        new BabiliPlugin({ comments: false }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: "minimal"
    }
};
```

and then my package.json (with command to build for prod):

```
{
  "name": "dipendentistatali",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && npm install && npm run build",
    "watch": "SET NODE_ENV=development && webpack --watch --color",
    "test": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=development && webpack -d --color",
    "buildProduction": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack -d --color",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.15",
    "angular2-cool-http": "^1.2.3",
    "angular2-toaster": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.16.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "2.2.4",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "ng2-modal": "0.0.22",
    "ng2-resource-rest": "^1.5.3",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^2.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.10",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.9.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

So if you launch npm start build it build the prod version in a directory that i called app_build/

Hope it can help you